# Custom Beamer theme does not arrange stuff as I expect

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, margins, themes

I am creating my own Beamer theme (let me call it *mytheme* in this thread) and currently working on title page. First I put the code shown below in `beamerinnerthememytheme.sty`, which is loaded by `\useinnertheme{mytheme}` in the main `beamerthememytheme.sty`.

```
% this is "beamerthememytheme.sty"
\mode<presentation>
% dependencies
\RequirePackage{tikz}
% load theme (outer and font themes are empty at the moment)
\useinnertheme{mytheme}
\useoutertheme{mytheme}
\usecolortheme{mytheme}
\usefonttheme{mytheme}
% settings
%% erase navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%% use "goshikku-tai" (Japanese counterpart of Alphabetical sans-serif) as a default Japanese font
%% when pTeX engine, its derivatives or luatex-ja package is used.
\ifdefined\kanjifamilydefault
    \renewcommand\kanjifamilydefault{\gtdefault}
\else
    \relax %
\fi
\mode<all>
% --------------------
% this is "beamerinnerthememytheme.sty"
\mode<presentation>
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}[1][]{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{title and subtitle}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox (0, 0) rectangle (\the\columnwidth, \the\paperheight); % assign a bounding box
            \fill[titlepagesidecolumn] (-\beamer@leftmargin, 0) rectangle (-0.35*\beamer@leftmargin, \the\paperheight);
            \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
                \node[anchor=west, font=\Huge\bfseries] at (0, 0.575*\the\paperheight) {\inserttitle};
            \else
                \node[anchor=west, font=\Huge\bfseries] at (0, 0.625*\the\paperheight) {\inserttitle};
                \node[anchor=west] at (0, 0.55*\the\paperheight) {\insertsubtitle};
            \fi
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{institute}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=west, font=\Large] at (0, 0.4*\the\paperheight) {\insertinstitute};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{author}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=west, font=\LARGE] at (0, 0.325*\the\paperheight) {\insertauthor};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{date}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=east, font=\small] at (\the\columnwidth, 0.15*\the\paperheight) {\insertdate};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\mode<all>   
% --------------------
% this is "beamercolorthememytheme.sty"
\mode<presentation>
\definecolor{titlepagesidecolumn}{HTML}{2792C3}
\mode<all>
% --------------------
% this is "mwe.tex"
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}
\usetheme{mytheme}
\title{Enter the title here}
\subtitle{Enter the subtitle here}
\institute{Enter the author's institute here}
\author{Enter the author's name here}
\date{Enter the date here}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following picture.

[image: output]

I have two problems with this code:

1. `institute`, `author` and `date` do not show up, and
2. there is a white space between the blue color bar and the upper edge of the frame although the vertical range of the bar is set from 0 to `\the\paperheight` (Is there something like `text margin top`?).

I know putting all the elements in one `beamercolorbox` environment makes the desired output with respect to the first problem.

[image: output2]

However, I want to split them in each `beamercolorbox` so that the appearance of every component can be changed respectively in documents' preamble via `\setbeamer***`.

How should I modify the code to solve those issues?

Comment: You need to provide a minimum working example.  Suggest you check http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/filecontents/filecontents.pdf for a way to include into a single MWE all the code.   Then you can provide a MWE that actually compiles to your current output.  Beamer is a very large package with very specific requirements and unless you provide a MWE, I would expect this question to be ignored as none of us (with a few wizard exceptions) are mindreaders.  Also please ask one question at a time.  The results arrive quicker and in the long run are more useful for the community.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Thank you for your suggestion. I updated the question. If there are still any defects, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Very good.  I would commend to you Gonzalo Medina answer below.  It illustrates both the solution to your design questions, but it is an excellent example of how to do simple beamer design in the preamble of the beamer slide show source code.  If you have to ship the source code to someone else you only need one file.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Yes, that's true. However, I want to unify the style of all the slides I make with Beamer, so I put these settings into the `.sty` files. My package may indeed be simple enough to write in the preamble now, but I will add other settings or features later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `\paperwidth` and `\paperheigh`, I'd suggest you to use the `current page.` family of nodes and to place everything with respect to those modes (this implies that you have to use the `remember picture,overlay` keys for each `tikzpicture` and that the document needs two runs for the elements to reach their final positions).

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{titlepagesidecolumn}{cyan}

\newlength\TitleLeftMargin
\setlength\TitleLeftMargin{20pt}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}[1][]{
    \leavevmode\begin{beamercolorbox}{title and subtitle}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \fill[titlepagesidecolumn] 
              (current page.north west) 
                rectangle 
              ([xshift=.5\beamer@leftmargin]current page.south west); 
            \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\relax
                \node[anchor=west, font=\Huge\bfseries] 
                  at ([yshift=20pt,xshift=\TitleLeftMargin]current page.west) 
                  {\inserttitle};
            \else
                \node[anchor=west, font=\Huge\bfseries] 
                  at ([yshift=30pt,xshift=\TitleLeftMargin]current page.west) 
                  {\inserttitle};
                \node[anchor=north west] 
                  at ([yshift=20pt,xshift=\TitleLeftMargin]current page.west) 
                  {\insertsubtitle};
            \fi
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{institute}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=west, font=\Large] 
              at ([yshift=-30pt,xshift=\TitleLeftMargin]current page.west) 
              {\insertinstitute};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{author}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=north west, font=\LARGE] 
              at ([yshift=-35pt,xshift=\TitleLeftMargin]current page.west) 
              {\insertauthor};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{date}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=south, font=\small] 
              at ([yshift=50pt]current page.south) 
            {\insertdate};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title}
\subtitle{The subtitle}
\institute{The Institute}
\author{The author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, why do you use `\TitleLeftMargin` instead of `\beamer@leftmargin`? Is it bad to use `\beamer@leftmargin` in this case?

Comment: @Merzong No, it is not bad. You can use it. However, I wasn't sure about the desired indentation, so I decided to define a new independant length. You can, of course, use `\beamer@leftmargin`.